# SQL Server and XAMPP

Tags: php, sql-server, xampp

I just want to ask is there a SQL Server when you only use XAMPP? 
If yes, where to find it?
If no, where do this server can be found?

Thanks!!

Comment: Very broad question... Yes you can use XAMPP with SQL Server but that needs some changes like installing drivers, SQL Server etc. AFAIK by default XAMPP uses MariaDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The M in XAMPP stands for MySQL (or is it MariaDB by now?). usually it's on localhost/phpMyAdmin I think, plus a port, if you have setup a different port than 80

Comment: I need to find the version of SQL Server. is that differ from XAMPP?

Comment: I really don't understand the question. The version will probably be shown on the phpMyAdmin page somewhere. Also, there is a distinct product called SQL Server (it's from Microsoft), and XAMPP has absolutely nothing to do with it, since XAMPP is free.

Comment: I see. I think that's the answer when someone asked you "What is your current SQL Server Version?"

Comment: If that is the literal question from someone who knows about database servers somewhat, "SQL Server" is synonymous with "MS SQL Server" (the Microsoft product)

Comment: Can you give me an example?